# Change mysql table join based on field value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is it possible in MySQL to change the JOIN of a table based on whats in a particular field of a record?

Example:

```
SELECT 
CASE table0.status
WHEN 1 THEN table1.id
WHEN 2 THEN table2.id
END
FROM 
table0, table1, table2
IF (table0.status = 1, INNER JOIN queue ON table1.id = table0.product, INNER JOIN queue ON table2.id = table0.product)
```

I need the joined table to be table1 if the value for 'product' in table0 = 1 or table2 if the value for 'product' in table0 is 2.

When I try the above example I only get mysql syntax errors.  Ive also tried it with CASE statement instead of the IF but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a subselect will be a better solution than `JOIN` in this case. You can use a `CASE` statement with a `SELECT` inside it.